# Check which rows coincide with specific row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very big table (1040 rows) of "values" and "attributes". The values are stored in column `A` and their respective attributes are stored in columns `I - CI`, so that the value in `A1` has a "vector" of attributes `I1:CI1` (which, by the way, are simply 0s and 1s).

I wish to find and print all values in the table that match the attributes of those of the value in `A1`. My attempt was this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ";TRUE; IF(AND(I1:CI1040 = I1:CI1); A1:A1040; ""))
```

but apparently, the AND function is bad for this (it always returns `#VALUE!`).
The idea of the formula is to check the whole range of attributes `I1:CI1040` and tell when a row coincides with the row `I1:CI1`, then return the corresponding value.

This doesn't work, and I don't know why.
Is there any way to compare rows in a given range?

Comment: so you want to compare full row to full row?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Comment: Use a 'helper' column in column CJ that concatenates all values from columns I:CI. Base your criteria on that 'helper' column.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBHUR.png

Comment: "..wish to find and print all values in the table that match the attributes.." the value you meant here is in column A right?